# Pytesseract not able to extract low contrast text from image

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract date from an image, but it is not working. I have more images with dates written in different colour.I have tried few preprocessing techniques like adaptive thresholding, erosion, dilation etc.

```
def cropright(img):
    (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
    crp = img[h-60:h, int((4*w)/7):w]
    crp = cv2.resize(crp, (0, 0), fx=5, fy=5,interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return(crp)

def extract_text(img):
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    img = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    plt.imshow(img)
    kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)   
    img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)  
    img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)
    plt.imshow(img)
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
    plt.imshow(img)
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img,lang='eng')
    return text

file = 'test.jpg'
img = cv2.imread("Request/" + file)
img = cropright(img)
plt.imshow(img)
text2 = extract_text(img)
print(text2)
```

Here is the image.I have more images with date written in different colours, so I need to develop a solution which will automatically work for all them
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQIsL.jpg)

Comment: did u try canny edge detection? might help as it focus more on contours

Answer (score 0):

I think by converting the image into gray scale you should be able to extract the date from the image irrespective of which color It is written in. I created an InstaFilters application that can apply filters to your images. The image is from that Web App. You can access it at https://share.streamlit.io/arkalsekar/instafilters/main/app.py

The code to apply a grayscale filter can be found on Github in the `filters` file:
https://github.com/arkalsekar/instafilters

[image: Image after applying grayscale filter]

You can even try these ones and believe that this should work. If it doesn't work then you can read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/pre-processing-in-ocr-fc231c6035a7) amazing post with some more intersting preprocessing techniques for OCR.

[image: Preprocessed image]

[image: Preprocessed image]

Comment: he did convert it to grayscale.

Comment: But he Even applied some threshold, Gaussian Blur and maybe That's why He is Unable to Get it. I think by using Just Gray scale He can get it.

Comment: ahh i see what you mean, i agree the gaussian blur might have made the characters unrecognizable

Comment: I tried gray scaling image(without thresholding and gaussian filter), but it not giving anything

Comment: I just edited the answer with some more Preprocessing and an article link. Let me Knwo if it helps